# Why can't I setup my Gigabyte Radeon R9 270x for 4 monitors?

Tags: graphics-card

I purchased this card and I'm having problems getting it to work with 4 monitors (1-HDMI, 1-DVI, 1-DVI, 1-Displayport)! The box states that the card can run 4 monitors but I can't seem to get it to work! Every time I try to extend the desktop to the 4th monitor I get an error that states that I must disable one of the other 3 monitors first. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Which version of the card? 2GB/4GB/Other?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same as you, believing you can plug 2 DVI, 1 HDMI and 1 DP, but looks like you can only use three at the same time without additional hardware.

When I say "additional hardware" I mean you can plug more if you buy a DisplayPort active splitter (google MSTDP123DP), you can buy one for 100USD and you'll be able to plug 3 monitors using only the DP output, so you can reach 4 or 5 using the two other DVI outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and a quick review, I'm assuming you have the top end GV-R927XOC-4GD-GA model, which supports up to 4 monitors and some pretty high resolutions for each.  My first guess is that your resolutions on the first three monitors are turned up too high.  The card has 4GB of total video memory available to use across the connected monitors.  And this card can support some pretty high resolutions on each monitor individually.

It is entirely possible that if you have the resolutions on the first three monitors cranked up to max, there isn't enough video memory left for you to enable the fourth monitor.  Try turning down the resolution levels on the other monitors one step at a time and see if you can enable the fourth monitor at some point.

Comment: How dumb os that a full HD in 32bits takes less than 8meg for a display, so four monitors take less than 32 meg, 4Go of RAM is 128 times enough...

Comment: You are way oversimplifying what video memory is used for. At absolute minimum, 67 MB is needed for a single 1080p display @32 bit (1920x1080x32). Next, video cards use frame buffering (i.e., the next frame or two are written to background memory before being displayed).  So that's 130MB or more. Memory is also used for the z-buffer data (managing 3D graphics, depth, textures, etc), which is what takes up the largest portion of memory. Even if it isn't being currently used, a portion of that memory is typically reserved for it. There's far more going on than just what you see on the screen.

Comment: @BBlake "At absolute minimum, 67 MB is needed for a single 1080p display at 32 bit (1920x1080x32)." No. You forgot to divide by 8. 1920 x 1080 x 32 bits  is about 8.3 megabytes.

Comment: 3x 1920x1200, 1x 2560x1440 works on my 2 GB card. Cranking up to max on 4 GB? Sorry, it's not possible.